# API request ~ Unsupported Method

Tags: php, http, curl, post

I am trying to retrieve data so it can broadcast on my website. I expect to receive an HTTP 200 (OK) response or HTTP 456 (not linked). Instead I'm receiving HTTP 411, Unsupported Method:

```
{"status":411,"message":"Unsupported request method. Contact the site administrator."}
```

If you try to send anything other than a HTTP POST request you will get this error.

It happens with this link, my other link(s) work just fine.

```
    <?php

    require_once 'faucethub.php';

    ?>

<?php
$url = 'https://faucethub.io/api/v1/checkaddress?api_key=HIDDEN';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$result_api = json_decode($data, true);

?>
```

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that endpoint should handle other types of requests?

Comment: Their documentation says you need to use a POST. You're using a GET. Guess what happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you are using the correct API credentials, then this is an issue on the server side--not a bug in your code. It's unclear if it's a bug on their side or if this is the intended behavior. If the API you're trying to use has documentation, consult that; otherwise, you'll need to reach out to someone at faucethub.io. They have configured the endpoint to accept POST requests only.

Comment: I' m sure that the link is alright, but I think the code is wrong. I can't seem to make it work :( If you type in the link in normal browser should it give the results?

Comment: If I type it into a browser, I get the same result (as expected, since the browser is also issuing a GET request). I'm assuming the "api_key" parameter gives an actual API key in your production app?